# Sound spectrogram

Tags: algorithm, audio

I have made an app that paints FFT to the screen realtime (from mic). Time on x-axis, frequency on y-axis and the color of the pixel represents the amplitude (pretty much a vanilla FFT spectrogram).

My problem is that even though I can see a pattern from the music there is also a lot of noise. Googling it I see people applying a logarithmic calculation to the amplitude. Should I be doing this? And if so, what would the formula look like? (I'm using C#, but I can translate the math into code so any sample is ok.)

I can bypass this problem by applying a color scheme showing lower values as darker colors. I'm just not sure if the audio is correctly represented without a logarithmic calculation on it.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of what the output currently looks like?

Comment: Better yet, use a log frequency axis, mirroring more closely the sensitivity of the ear, To understand the difference, see http://wikidelia.net/wiki/Spectrogram for examples

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Representation of the amplitude on a logarithmic scale approximates the sensitivity of the human auditory system, and therefore gives you a better representation of what you hear, as compared to a non-logarithmic scale. Mathematically, all you have to do is:

```
Alog = 20*log10 (abs (A))
```

Where `A` is the amplitude of the FFT data, and `Alog` is the output. the factor of `20` is just a convention and has no effect on the image, which you probably scale anyway to a color-scheme.

**EDIT**

Explanation regarding the `20` factor: The dB (decibel) unit is a logarithmic unit measuring **ratios**: it represents a scale on which the distance between 100 and 10, is the same as between 1000 and 100 (since they have the same ratio: 1000/100 = 100/10). If you measure it in dB you get:

```
10*log10 (1000/100) = 10*log10 (100/10) = 10
```

The factor of `10` is because `deci` means `tenth`, which means 1 Bel is 10 deciBels, (like 1 kilogram is 1000 grams)

Since the human auditory system is also (approximately) measuring ratios, it makes sense to measure sound level on a logarithmic scale, i.e measure the ratio of sound level to some reference value. Since the level of a sound is associated with the power (in Watts) of the sound wave, you actually measure the ratio of powers P/Pref. Also, the power is proportional to the amplitude squared, so all in all you get:

```
10*log10 (P/Pref) = 10*log10 (A^2 / Aref^2) = 20*log10 (A/Aref)
```

by the log rules. That's the origin of the `20` factor - remember that in the computer the audio is represented by the instantaneous amplitude of the sound wave.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain 20 a bit further?

Answer (score 3):

Viewing your spectrogram logarithmically is, indeed, a better way to look a audio signals. Keep in mind also, that you need good [resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STFT#Example) in both time-direction and frequency-direction. If you have too few bins in one or the other, it might look strange.

Another important point is that viewing your STFT on a log scale is *not* a denoising technique. What you see as "noise" might be actual [noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_%28electronics%29) or it could be things like [harmonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28music%29), [transients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient_%28oscillation%29#Electrical_Engineering), [spectral leakage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_leakage) and other things that are expected to be there. Depending on your application, if you need to do short-time analysis of a signal, a [wavelet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet_transform) transform might be more suitable for your needs. It takes away certain disadvantages of the STFT such as constant window size.